# email.invalid not work in angularmaterial

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use AngularMaterial, and using forms validation

```
 <section class="signup-form">
  <form fxLayout='column' fxLayoutAlign='center' #f='ngForm' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit(f)'>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        type='email'
        matInput
        placeholder="Email"
        name='email'
        #emailInput='ngModel'
        required
        ngModel>
        <mat-error *ngIf="emailInput.invalid">Invalid</mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="emailInput.hasError('required')">Field must not be empty</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="warn" [disabled]='!f.valid'>Submit</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

The problem is it does not show Invalid validation, only required validation works. Please help.

I am using `"@angular/material": "^5.2.5",`

**EDIT:**
I forgot to add the validator pattern. Now it works.

Comment: Why can't you use '!emailInput.valid' instead?

Comment: Tried it, but it a wrong email format is also treated validated.

Comment: @SakshamGupta `emailInput.invalid` would be better actually

Answer (score 0):

Check this example from official documentation

[Email Error](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples)